# How to delete polygons in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

how can i delete old polygons in rviz. For Marker there is the command:

```
visualization_msgs::Marker::DELETE
```

I didn't found something similar for polygons. Does someone know the command for it? I searched also in google, but unfortunaly i find no answer yet.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173124/how-to-delete-polygons-in-rviz/) by [mr42](https://answers.ros.org/users/18686/mr42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The concept of "delete" doesn't exist for most display types, because they're visualizing the state of a continuous stream of data. Most display types do have a history or buffer size, which indicates how many messages to keep and display; perhaps you can adjust this value?

If you're explicitly trying to present a user interface in rviz, you should probably be using markers or interactive markers, which give you more control.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0